# Phrasematcher Spacy error

Tags: python, spacy

I am using Phrasematcher in Spacy and getting an error like this -

```
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "spacy/matcher.pyx", line 505, in spacy.matcher.PhraseMatcher.__init__ (spacy/matcher.cpp:11371)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 positional arguments (1 given)
```

It is asking for 2 arguments but according to [spacy documentation](https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher#call) we can give it one argument also. Did anybody faced this error? How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your version of Spacy is out of date with the documentation? I get the same error on a machine running an older version of Spacy, and PhraseMatcher appears to be new in 2.0.0+.

See: https://spacy.io/usage/v2#migrating-matcher

Comment: Glad to hear it! Spacy is a great library. Just be careful with 2.0.0+, as there are still some kinks being worked out. The Github issues are a good place to check: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues